# How to get checkedboxlist item Id from C# winform

Tags: c#, winforms

How i can get id when i click on item of checkedboxlist. Currently i am getting string name of the Item but i want to get id when i click on text item in checkedboxlist ?

**Here is my code:**

```cs
private void BindChackBox2()
{
    try
    {
        SqlConnection con = new  SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager
            .ConnectionStrings["Conec"].ConnectionString);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT Id, Task  FROM Mytodo_Task 
            Where Status='Ongoing' And Username='" + Login.recuser + "'", con);
        SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        sda.Fill(dt);

        for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            checkedListBoxongoing.Items.Add(dt.Rows[i]["Task"].ToString() +" "+ dt.Rows[i];
            ["Id"].ToString());
        }
    }
    catch { }
}
```

Comment: Simplest solution: use `string.Split()`

Comment: You could try using checkedListBoxongoing.SelectedIndex , I hope that works for your purpose :)

Comment: I think with selected index it will get the index of that item in the list. I want to get the id of that list item.